# ASP .Net Web Applications Resource Consumption on Windows Azure Websites.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure websites claim that basic and standard mode may host up to **500*** websites wherein:

> Basic and Standard sites run on dedicated machines. The actual number
>   of sites that you can host on these machines depends on the activity
>   of the sites, the size of the machine instances, and the corresponding
>   resource utilization

On my setup, i have 18 websites (9 for production and 9 for Q/A), running ASP .Net web applications deployed into a website hosted at a standard S2 (medium) plan: 2 Cores and 3.5 GB Ram.

Each website has two continuous w3wp.exe processes. I already know that one is for hosting the SCM  service (used for website diagnostics and deployment) and the other that actual host the .net web application itself.

**The Problem**

Memory consumption have become a issue, currently the setup is consuming around 88% of memory. 
First i thought it would be a memory leak but but a)we have very few or none requests for those sites yet (still launching the service) and; b) along the past days memory consumption has stabilized at 88%.

*Then i try something else:*

**Phase 1**

So, i create the simplest ASP .Net Web project (sampled from MSFT) and deployed into a new website hosted at a standard S2 (medium) plan: 2 Cores and 3.5 GB Ram.

It turns out, this simple setup (1 ASP .net web application on 1 website hosted at a standard (s2) machine ) actually consumes **38% of Memory**.

**Phase 2**
Then i create a new website in the same host plan and redeploy the same asp .net project. The consumption rises to **41%**.

**Conclusions?**

*Help me out, its safe to say that:*

- A simple ASP .Net MVC project consumes around 3% == 105 mb of ram.
- In Phase 1, the Ram consumption was 38%. 38% - 3%  == 35% (1225 mb of ram to the S.O)

*Also:*

- Is there anything that we can do in order to lower the memory consumption across the 18 websites? Is there any change of reusing processes between them?
- Can you please indicate some resource where we can see generic metrics about memory and resources consumption on azure websites and IIS (where we can see the lower threshold of memory consumption for an ASPNET MVC website on azure)?
- We need to make some decisions about our strategy regarding azure infrastructure and decide if azure websites is a good option for us.

Thankful for any reply.

Comment: Note that the 3.5 GB RAM includes the memory used by the OS. You have an entire VM dedicated just for your use, and that VM has a total of 3.5 GB of RAM available to it

Comment: Yes, that is correct @ZainRizvi. And by my analysis, the OS is eating 1.2 GB. 
My concern is more related to the fact that one website with the simplest ASP .Net MVC project consume 3% of Memory (100mb). Which may meaning that such VM can only host 20 MVC projects distribute in 20 Websites. And that is the problem.

Comment: That sounds about right if all websites are being actively used (that's the same amount of sites you can put on a regular machine with similar specs).  The difference with Azure Websites is that usually when you have a whole bunch of sites most of them normally don't receive much traffic. In order to scale up to hosting many websites, Azure Websites will tear down the sites that haven't had any requests for some time and free up resources for other sites to use. Now when someone tries to make an http request to a site that's been torn down Azure Websites will bring that site back up

Comment: @ZainRizvi - in your perspective such values are normal and there is nothing that i can do? 

I mean, if the values are normal, the only solution for me is : A) move to a S3 instance (7gb ram) or; B) Split the 18 websites in half (or so) and running 2 VM instance. Each with 9 websites.

Comment: It depends. Are you expecting constant traffic on all those sites? Even the SCM sites get torn down if you're not using any of their features, freeing up resources. If you setup autoscale you'll be using the minimum number of machines during low traffic times and can scale out to the number needed when many of your sites are being hit